# Script to list extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a windows batch script that lists all extensions in a directory, recursively.

The desired behaviour is this:
You start the bat file in directory "a" which contains the following files: b.txt, c.png, d.txt, e.jpeg, f.jpg.

The script should output the following:
txt
png
jpeg
jpg

I would like the each extension to be in a new line, alphabetic ordering is not necessary.

Comment: You need to show your own efforts to solve the task, providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts...

Answer (score 2):

The method you linked to is probably overkill for what you want.

Do a `for /r` loop to get all files recursively and set a variable named the same as the extension (the value isn't important, we need only the variable to be defined)
Then do a `for /f` loop to list the variables (with `set .` - all of them start with a dot conveniently because the `%%~x` modifier gets the extension with the dot (`.txt`)). Then just sort them alphabetically, if needed:

```
@echo off & setlocal
for /r %%a in (*) do set "%%~xa=X" 2>nul
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set .') do echo %%a
```

(edit: removed the `sort`, because `set .` already sorts alphabetically - thank you @LotPings for the hint)

Comment: With `set /A "%%~xa+=1"` you could also count the occurrences of the unique extensions in one go. (`set .` output will be alpha sorted by default) +1

Comment: What is `2>0` for?

Comment: @aschipfl: suppress error messages with files that have no extension (tries to create a variable with no name)

Comment: But you mean `2> nul`, right?

Comment: @aschipfl *facepalm* Can I blame that to the heat?

Comment: Ha ha, oh yes, absolutely...

Comment: IMHO it would be _convenient_ to indicate that `"%%~xa=."` part _automatically_ includes a dot before the extension AND to assign any value, _except a dot_, to the variables. Otherwise, a novice could think that the dot before the names is provided by the value placed after the equal sign...